# I’m 5,4 120 pounds and can’t pull rope up on extension ladder Why?

Tags: ladder

I am having trouble operating (pulling the rope) an extension ladder?

I need to do this to get certified to work for Dish.

Is there a better way too easily extend the rope ladder, without requiring much muscles to do so.

Comment: Is it just the rope?  Can you move the extension part by hand?

Comment: Imagine rope is jammed or you are pulling on the wrong end.  Whole ladder should weigh 30 to 40 pounds, about half that for the extension.  The top needs to be free from jamming on a wall.  Is there any locks on the ladder?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement

Comment: Because you didn't eat your Wheaties.

Comment: You're not standing on the ladder when you're pulling are you?

Comment: Reach high when you grab the rope, so you are pulling straight down.

Comment: @gnicko  Small is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct.

Comment: @JACK -- Small is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct.

Comment: @Ruskes altering certified equipment is not a solution and posts should be on topic - a requirement for new, and established, users on here.

Comment: @Ruskes - Don't get excited...I've seen more than one person do that.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the rope around your shoe at about one step high and while holding the loose end, step on it, ending up in using your weight to pull the ladder up by one step at the time.

It will look stupid but it will work and get you the job.